# How can I have multiple instances of one controller for multiple templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to use a reusable controller for a generic template

html

```
<div class="row col-lg-10 pull-right">

   <div ng-init="catId = 1" ui-view="firstQuadrant"></div>
   <div ng-init="catId = 2" ui-view="secondQuadrant"></div>

</div>

<div class="row col-lg-10 pull-right">

   <div ng-init="catId = 3" ui-view="thirdQuadrant"></div>
   <div ng-init="catId = 4" ui-view="fourthQuadrant"></div>

</div>
```

code snippet from my views object in `$stateProvider`:

```
views : {
    'firstQuadrant@home': {
      templateUrl: "../partials/quadrant/quadrant.html",
      controller: "QuadrantCtrl"
    },
    'secondQuadrant@home': {
      templateUrl: "../partials/quadrant/quadrant.html",
      controller: "QuadrantCtrl"
    },
    'thirdQuadrant@home': {
      templateUrl: "../partials/quadrant/quadrant.html",
      controller: "QuadrantCtrl"
    },

    'fourthQuadrant@home': {
      templateUrl: "../partials/quadrant/quadrant.html",
      controller: "QuadrantCtrl"
    }
}
```

controller code

```
.controller('QuadrantCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'categories', 'utils', 
   function ($scope, $rootScope, categories, utils) {

  $scope.$watch('catId', function () {
      console($scope.catId); 
      $scope.categories = categories;
      $scope.name = "It works! weee";
      $scope.score = 99;
      $scope.items = utils.findById($scope.categories, $scope.catId);
  });     

}]);
```

It only seems to use the last controller being instantiated (catId = 4)
how can I have 4 isolated scopes? Do I have to use directives instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario should work *(not sure if this is good design)*. There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdazVPARXiD7eorPe91Y?p=preview)

But we have to move the switch **`catId`** from ng-init into state defintion. Into resolve

If the states are defined like this:

```
// home
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.layout.html',
    controller : "rootController",
  })
```

the child state with multi-views

```
  .state('child', {
    parent: "home",
    url: '/child',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.example.html',
    views : {
       'firstQuadrant@home': {
          templateUrl: "tpl.quadrant.html",
          controller: "QuadrantCtrl",
          resolve: { catId : function(){ return 1 } },
        },
        'secondQuadrant@home': {
          templateUrl: "tpl.quadrant.html",
          controller: "QuadrantCtrl",
          resolve: { catId : function(){ return 2 } },
        },

        'thirdQuadrant@home': {
          templateUrl: "tpl.quadrant.html",
          controller: "QuadrantCtrl",
          resolve: { catId : function(){ return 3 } },
        },

        'fourthQuadrant@home': {
          templateUrl: "tpl.quadrant.html",
          controller: "QuadrantCtrl",
          resolve: { catId : function(){ return 4 } },
        }
    }
  })
```

And simplified controller creates random number in the scope

```
.controller('QuadrantCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'catId' 
, function ($scope, $rootScope, catId) {

      $scope.catId = catId;

      console.log($scope.catId); 

      $scope.random = Math.random() * 100;

}])
```

Each view is then independent with its own instance of controller and $scope

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdazVPARXiD7eorPe91Y?p=preview)

Then we can see results like this

**quadrant**
random number in the scope: 32.40865177940577
catId: 1

**quadrant**
random number in the scope: 17.18798188958317
catId: 2

**quadrant**
random number in the scope: 76.22438217513263
catId: 3

**quadrant**
random number in the scope: 41.46456739399582
catId: 4

if the quadrant template is:

```
<h4>quadrant</h4>
<p>random number in the scope: {{random}}</p>
<p>catId: {{catId}}</p>
```

All that is strictly following the documentation:

#### [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

The [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdazVPARXiD7eorPe91Y?p=preview) with above stuff

Comment: what is if(!catId){return;} doing exactly?

I also saw your comment on it may be bad design, what would you recommend?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you reload the plunker? I just finished some last adjustments. You should see now [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdazVPARXiD7eorPe91Y?p=preview) that the states are now having the resolve. This is a place where we can configure the **catId**. Check it in action and all should be clear